# Remove an old domain from bitnami ssl certificate

Tags: ssl, bitnami

I am unable to renew my ssl certicate in bitnami because I can't revoke a domain. How can I remove the domain from bitnami?

Comment: Your question is offtopic here as not related to programming, but in short you can't change anything inside a certificate once issued. You have to generate a new certificate having the properties you need and optionnally revoke old one, or just let it expire.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek if it's unrelated to StackOverflow, why are there ssl and bitnami tags? OP doesn't want to change the certificate, but to remove the domain from the server.

Comment: " if it's unrelated to StackOverflow, why are there ssl and bitnami tags?" Because you can have **programming** related problems related to these 2 tags. Renewing a certificate is not a programming problem. As for " but to remove the domain from the server. " that is certainly not what is written in the question, which shows it is also vague, poorly worded and lacking details, lots of other reason to make it offtopic here. Server administration is also offtopic here, there is [sf] or [su] for those cases.